# No document classes available in Lyx, Linux

Tags: lyx, document-classes, linux

I just installed Linux Mint on my computer and I'm having a problem with the Lyx application which I never had with Windows. I downloaded it via the software manager, so I was hoping that there wouldn't be any complications during the installation, yet I'm unable to view my document in .pdf format or even save it as one. Also, under Documents->Settings->Document Class, all classes are grayed out and marked as unavailable.

I searched around a little, but I could only find solutions concerning the WIndows and Mac environments, and being a Linux noob, I thought I should ask here since I can't find a solution for the life of me. Is there a way I can solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you have a LaTeX distribution installed at all in on your Linux partitions?

Comment: Open a terminal window and start LyX from there by typing lyx in. Then go to Tools>Reconfigure, close LyX and check the terminal window for error messages or anything suspicious. I'd also check if pdflatex can be started from terminal.

Comment: @christianHupfer Nope, no other distributions installed

Comment: @HarryK.: I don't know the LyX Linux package on Linux Mint, but it is most likely shipping the LyX editor binaries only and not TeX/LaTeX etc. in addition.  You have to install a LaTeX distribution, preferably TeXLive in addition.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip tried both of these. No errors appear in the terminal. Also pdflatex was not installed, so I did, and starting pdflatex gives this message:`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer if you don't mind me asking, how would I go around doing that?

Comment: @HarryK.: Your statements are confusing. First you claim there is no distribution, then you show the output of TL 2015 (!!!)....

Comment: Look for and install some base packages of texlive. Like these here https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=170852

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I may have misunderstood your question there. Like I said, I just installed Linux today and I'm still trying to get used to it. I apologize if I made a mistake, but could you please elaborate your question? Have I done something wrong during the installation?

Comment: @PhilipPirrip tried installing a few packages but there was no change. However, I did eventually get an error message which states I need to install a certain extarticle.cls file to get the article class document to (hopefully) work. Until then, the program will not be able to compile my documents.

Comment: Confusion regarding "distribution" having two meanings: (1) Linux Mint, as a Linux distribution, (2) TeXlive, as a TeX distribution.